# Search between two patterns and print the data from first pattern to second pattern multiple times, excluding non-matching blocks

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have to search for a specific string in the reverse order and print it.

In the below example I want to search from the pattern `not in order` until the pattern `number of`.

Example: input file contains:

```
number of characters a[1] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[1] is not in order

number of characters a[3] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[3] is in order


number of characters a[2] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[2] is not in order
```

output should be:

```
number of characters a[1]
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[1] is not in order

number of characters a[2] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[2] is not in order
```

Comment: I don't understand why the second paragraph about `a[3]` is missing in the output. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't want the second paragraph... I have to print only paragraph contains "not in order"

Comment: is it always 4 lines above "not in order" ?

Comment: no , some paragraph having 5, 23, 100, 200 lines

Comment: Ah, now I see. Sorry, I didn't realize it says "is in order" there.

Answer (score 4):

Using `in order` with a newline as the paragraph delimiter, we can do:

```
awk -v RS='in order\n' '/not/{print $0 "in order"}'
```

`awk` treats text separated by the pattern in `RS` (record separator) as records, and each operation is done on a record. So `/not/` tests if the record matches `not`, and then we print the record (`$0`) along with the separator text, which was removed by awk.

So:

```
$ mawk -v RS='in order\n' '/not/{print $0 "in order"}' foo
number of characters a[1]
reg1
reg2
reg3
info a[1] is not in order


number of characters a[2]
reg1
reg2
reg3
info a[2] is not in order
```

Comment: cant we grep only the pattern "not in order" until the pattern "number of" because I can see some of the paragraph are coming in between

Comment: Show us the sample text for which that happens.

Comment: Warning
info
number of characters a[1] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[1] is not in order

number of characters a[3] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[3] is in order
helperflop


number of characters a[2] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[2] is not in order
number of characters a[4] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[4] is in order
helperflop

Comment: Edit it into your question, please, with proper formatting.

Comment: you should check for `/ is not$/` (ie "is not" as end of line), to be safer on the boundary matching

Comment: @OlivierDulac good idea, but in this case I think the problem is more in extra text in the lines (I see `helperflop` in the comments above, but without formatting, I cannot really make out where it belongs)

Answer (score 3):

If the blocks have to end with a line that contains `is in order` or `is not in order`, we can delete things between them...

```
$ sed '/is not in order/,/is in order/ {/is not in order/n;d}' file
number of characters a[1] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[1] is not in order


number of characters a[2] 
reg1 
reg2 
reg3 
info a[2] is not in order
```

#### Notes:

- `/is not in order/,/is in order/` find the lines between `is not in order` and `is in order`, inclusive
- `{some commands}` group these commands
- `/is not in order/n` skip the line with this pattern from the next command
- `d` delete the specified lines

It might seem convoluted to find the line and then find it again to skip it, but we can't use an empty line instead, or `sed` will turn on its *operate here* flag at the next empty line and keep going until the next `is in order`, which will delete too much.

Answer (score 3):

another approach:

```
tac file | awk ' BEGIN {weprint=0 ; rem="not necessary, but for clarity"}
  /is not in order$/ { weprint=1 ;}
  ( weprint == 1)    { print $0  ;   rem="same remark here..."; }
  /^number of/       { weprint=0 ;}
' | tac
```

which could be shortened if needed...

If you want the separator line:  change the last line as

```
"/^number of/" { print ; weprint=0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /not in order/' file
```

The `-00` option reads the file by paragraphs.
The `-n` adds an implicit loop over all the paragraphs in the file.
Then, print the paragraph if it contains the desired text "not in order".